# Retrieve list of files from remote server A from different server B

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the list of file details from some remote server which is different from the server where I am executing the exe.

```
Server.Path(servername + "d:\foldername\")
```

Answer (score 4):

You have different possibilities:

1. Write a web service application you call from your exe running on server B.
2. If you're running on a domain, you might create a share on server B and accessing it using `\\serverb\sharename` This would allow for integrated security using Windows users

Depending on what other functionality you want to add later and the sensitivity of the data, there is an implication on security.

Comment: Not necessarily a web service, but *some* sort of remote service.

Answer (score 0):

FTP is another option (if enabled on remote server).

Comment: Dont have an ftp access to the specified folders.